# Calling pointer in Function

Tags: c, pointers, error-handling

```
int * ShiftTable(char Pattern[]){
    int PatternSize = strlen(Pattern);
    int i;
    int j;
    int * Table = malloc(sizeof(char) * 26);
    for(i = 0; i <= 25 ; i++ )
    Table[i] = PatternSize;
    for(j = 0; PatternSize - 2 ; j++)
    Table[Pattern[j]] = PatternSize - 1 - j;
    return Table ;
} 

int main(){

    char y [] = "aslifee";
    int d = ShiftTable(y);
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i <= 26 ; i++)
    printf("%d ", d[i]); 

    printf(" weerwerwef "); // I write here because  when I run, also this code doesn't work so I made a mistake.
    getchar();   
}
```

Hi everyone, I want to do horspool algorithm's shift table. Then I have to use pointer to return an array(in fact pointer). I looked a lot of examples on the Internet, but I couldn't find clear explanation for my problem. When I run this code first black screen comes then I take "windows stoped working" error. Where am I wrong? What should I do to solve this problem?

I fixed, My problem was for(j = 0; PatternSize - 2 ; j++) in this line and 
Table[Pattern[j]] = PatternSize - 1 - j; in this line. 1st line I made a syntax error, it should be for(j = 0; j<=PatternSize - 2 ; j++); 2nd line Pattern[j] returns ASCI value. "a"'s ASCI value is 97 so I should fix like these : Table[Pattern[j]-97] = PatternSize - 1 - j; Finally the following code is running. Thanks everybody and sorry for off-topic problem.

```
int * ShiftTable(char Pattern[]){
        int PatternSize = strlen(Pattern);
        int i;
        int j;
        int * Table = malloc(sizeof(int) * 26);
        for(i = 0; i <= 25 ; i++ )
        Table[i] = PatternSize;
        for(j = 0; j<=PatternSize - 2 ; j++)
        Table[Pattern[j]-97] = PatternSize - 1 - j;
        return Table ;
        }
int main(){
        char y [] = "aslifee";
        int *d = ShiftTable(y);
        int i;
        for(i = 0 ; i<26 ; i++)
        printf("%d ", d[i]); 
        getchar();
        }
```

Comment: If the linker complains *"undefined reference to `ShifTable'"*, is it too much asked that you check your code for references to that function?

Comment: (1) `int * Table = malloc(sizeof(char) * 26);` : `sizeof(char)` --> `sizeof(int)`

Comment: (2) `Table[Pattern[j]]` : `Pattern[j]` range not 0～25.

Comment: (3) `int d = ShiftTable(y);` : `int *d`

Comment: (4) `i <= 26` : should be `i < 26` or `i <= 25`

Comment: Bluepixy thanks, In fact last night I fixed all of them, I saw later all of them. My problem here, I am aware of Pattern[j] 's range not 0-25 but In algorithm  ALGORITHM 
ShiftTable(P [0..m − 1])
//Fills the shift table used by Horspool’s and Boyer-Moore algorithms
//Input: Pattern P[0..m − 1] and an alphabet of possible characters
//Output: Table[0..size − 1] indexed by the alphabet’s characters and
// filled with shift sizes computed by formula (7.1)
for i ←0 to size − 1 do Table[i]←m
for j ←0 to m − 2 do Table[P[j ]]←m − 1− j
return Table
How to adapt this algorithm to C???

Answer (score 1):

Typo error. Change:

```
int d = ShifTable(y);
```

to

```
int d = ShiftTable(y);
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed but still I have a problem. I edited my question.